# Does ActiveMQ "Classic" require ZooKeeper anymore?

Tags: activemq-classic

I'm investigating the usage of some message broker that does not depend on any external services. I hit upon ActiveMQ "Classic" which was using replicated LevelDB and that apparently required ZooKeeper services. With ActiveMQ now switching to KahaDB, is ZooKeeper still required for using ActiveMQ?

Any recommendations on what the best message broker would be, my deployment does not deal with high scale pub-sub. I'm looking for something very lightweight that can support reliable message delivery, persistent messages and HA.

Answer (score 1):

ActiveMQ does not require ZooKeeper to run, the default store KahaDB does not have a replication feature such as that in LevelDB and so does not need any ZooKeeper instances.

For HA you might want to look into ActiveMQ Artemis which offers solutions beyond what exists in ActiveMQ proper.

Answer (score -1):

I found the answer to my own question

http://activemq.apache.org/kahadb-master-slave.html

yes, even KahaDB requires zookeeper at the moment

Comment: This is incorrect, KahaDB does not require zookeeper